# The Proofs of Prime Number Theorems

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I had decided to study and understand the proof of prime number theorem.
I had tried to approximate the value of  $\frac{\pi(x)}{x}$ and have seen some videos which gives the intuition about the approximation.

So I want to ask for references for a beginner. I mean it should be either understandable easily or with a bit of hardwork. It shouldn't be very difficult. The thing is to get comfortable with this new topic analytic number theory, I first need to go through an easy proof.

$1 $ More question I would like to ask is that-Isn't Tom Apostol's Book on analytic number theory has a nice and systematic analytic proof of that theorem. What are the topics I need to study to understand the proof of prime number theorem by Tom Apostol?

P.S- I had already done courses in Number Theory, Real Analysis, Complex Analysis

Comment: You should start by first improving your knowledge of number theory and calculus before moving on prime number theory.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit  Yes, I had done well in the courses of Number Theory, Calculus , Real and Complex Analysis

Comment: Rudin's book on Functional Analysis has  a proof but you have to study enough Functional Analysis before you can read that proof.

Comment: I find Landau's proof the easiest and most transparent for starting. [Hildebrand's notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main.pdf) give a pretty good exposition IMO.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank You, I am sure that it is good reference for me to start with

Comment: It depends a lot on your level in complex analysis and Fourier analysis. For example look at a proof of $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi/\sin(\pi s)$

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you mention exactly where is the proof. I guess it has been proved in parts? But where exactly it is. I have completed chapter 0 & 1

Comment: @SunShine It's in chapter 5. While the contents of the previous chapters are important and interesting in their own right, you don't need most of it to understand the proof. The big ingredient of the proof is the residue theorem/Cauchy's integral theorem, which you should be comfortable with after a course in Complex analysis. Then you also need a bit of real analysis for some estimates.

Answer (score 2):

At the 100th birthday of the prime number theorem Don Zagier published *Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem* in the American Mathematical Monthly. It's only three pages, without the Historical Remarks. You can embed it in a first course of complex analysis.

It's in the October issue of American Mathematical Monthly **104** (1997), 705–708.

Comment: I disagree so much with your answer

Comment: @reuns: You should indicate what you don't like.

Comment: @reuns what is there to disagree about in this answer? Do you think Zagier did not publish the proof in the Amer. Math. Monthly in 1997? That his version of the proof can't be part of a course in complex analysis?  Or that this proof can't be understood by a beginner but you know other proofs that can?

Comment: @KCd Sorry but did you ever study the PNT ? If the proof is 20 pages long in the books it is not for nothing, nobody recommends the "short proof".

Comment: Sure I've studied PNT.  And I've taught courses that include a proof of PNT using Newman's method.  The proof is not 20 pages long in "the books".  In the book of De Koninck and Luca the treatment of Newman's proof is 7 pages. In "Geometric and Analytic Number Theory by Hlawka, Tascher, and Schoissengeier the proof of PNT by Newman's theorem is 5-6 pages (this includes the proof of nonvanishing of $\zeta(s)$ on the line $\sigma = 1$, which Newman takes as his starting point without proof). In Jameson's book "The Prime Number Theorem", the proof of Newman's theorem takes around 5 pages.